# How can I prevent my error messages from disappearing?

Tags: php

How can I prevent my error messages from disappearing? My error messages appear on my page and then after a few seconds they disappear, is there a php way to prevent it from happening? I have tried different " $ERRORs " ways of writing the code but the errors keep on diapering after page refresh. Does anybody know how I can prevent my error messages from disappearing?

Comment: PHP errors don't disappear.

Comment: You need to give A LOT more details. Your post is even contradictory - you're saying that the errors disappear after a few seconds but that they're disappearing on page refresh. What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: Try turning on an error.log file in your php.ini configuration and you won't need to access the screen to find your errors.

Comment: After the page refreshes they disappear. So the page refreshes and after a few seconds they disappear

Comment: No the errors appear just that they disappear after a few seconds

Comment: are you talking about post values?

Comment: Yea about email post error messages

Comment: Yea looks like I gots it......   =O !  BOOOYAH!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this happen. It seems to sometimes happen BEFORE the  tag is sent to the browser. It seems, from my experience, that if PHP spits out an error before the  tag, then, depending on the CSS, the error can be hidden. What you can do is right-click and view source. The error is still there, you just can't see it.